# Проверка параметров

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Скажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли я делаю, проверяя параметры вот так?

```
if (!empty($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['pass']) && !empty($_POST['pass1']) && !empty($_POST['question']) && !empty($_POST['answer']) && !empty($_POST['mail']) && !empty($_POST['antibot']))
```

Есть ли более изящный, правильный способ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так, например:

```
$ok = false;
foreach (array('login', 'pass', 'pass1', 'question', 'answer', 'mail', 'antibot') as $code)
  if (!empty($_POST[$code]))
    $ok = false; // или handleError('reg', $code) или еще что-то...
if ($ok) {
  // all is ok
  }
```

Если такое случается часто, лучше вынести в функцию

```
function emptyPost() {
  foreach (func_get_args() as $code)
    if (empty($_POST[$code]))
      return true;
  return false;
  }
if (!emptyPost('login', 'pass', 'pass1', 'question', 'answer', 'mail', 'antibot')) {
  // all is ok
}
```

В общем, советую написать функции проверки/валидации, ваши собственные, чтобы такого нагромождения не было.

Answer (score 0):

empty проверяет пустая ли переменная. Но при этом она должна существовать. Существует ли проверяется через isset. Далее, стоит разделить эти проверки поотму что например почту, стоит проверить на правильность формата, пароль на длину, логин на допустимость. Тоисть от вашей проверки практической пользы ноль.

Comment: Я не хочу развертывать здесь весь код. Там все проверяется, это лишь проверка на существования входящих параметров. 
Я не чайник... 

Плюс ко всему - Вы не ответили на мой вопрос.

Есть ли более лучшая альтернатива моей проверке?

Comment: Если вы уже проверили существует ли переменная, то зачем вам эта пустота? Есть правила для проверки логина? Ну так примените его сразу же, и если правила проверки грамотно составлены то оно откинет сразу же и пустое значение. Тоже самое и про почту. Я просто не вижу смысла проверять на пустоту вообще.

Comment: По вашему isset быстрее empty ?

Comment: Не то чтобы быстрее, у них разная логика работы и предназначение. Подробнее можете почитать тут `http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/php/113253/`

Comment: empty, между нами, коварная штука. )) empty(0) === true